# Switch between mobile and desktop view in power bi embedded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a power bi report with both desktop and mobile views. I'd like the browser to switch between these views as it resizes. The only way I can currently achieve this is to embed two instances of the report into the browser, one mobile the other desktop, and hide and show them depending on the browser size.

The problem with this is that if I set some filter values when in the desktop view then, narrow the browser so that the mobile view is shown, then the filter values are not same, this obviously being because there are in reality two separate reports.

The other downside of this approach is that I am presumably also incurring the performance cost on my database of generating two reports.

What can I do to only embed a single report that can dynamically switch between mobile and desktop views?

**UPDATE Following response below, test code to toggle layout between mobile and custom layout**

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
    if (vm.report === null)
        return;

    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    var newLayout = models.LayoutType.Custom;
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        newLayout = models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait;
    }

    if (vm.report.config.settings.layoutType !== newLayout) {
        const newSettings = { layoutType: newLayout };
        vm.report.updateSettings(newSettings);
    }}
```

**UPDATE 2, Added code to show how the report is generated**

```
        // report config 
    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
    var config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: result.accessToken,
        embedUrl: result.embedUrl,
        id: result.reportId,
        permissions: models.Permissions.View,
        viewMode: models.ViewMode.Read,
        settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: false,
            navContentPaneEnabled: false,
            background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
            layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
            customLayout: {
                displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToPage
            }
        }
    };

    // get elements and embed them
    var desktopReportContainer = $('.reportContainer')[0];
    vm.report = powerbi.embed(desktopReportContainer, config);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of embedding two instances of a report you can do:

1. Change the layout type by updating settings like here: [change-layout-example](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile#change-layout-example).
   The downside of this approach is that your user's cross filters will not be saved when changing layout.
2. Before changing the layout type, save a bookmark and then after changing the layout type apply the saved bookmark:

   ```
   function changeLayout(layoutType) {
       report.bookmarksManager.capture()
       .then(function (capturedBookmark) {
           var bookmarkState = capturedBookmark.state;

           var config = {
               layoutType: layoutType
           };
           report.updateSettings(config).then(function () {
               report.bookmarksManager.applyState(bookmarkState);
           })
       })
   }
   ```

   Please note that you will have to add error handling code to the sample above.
3. Use Custom layout instead of mobile layout like here: [Dynamic report layout](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#).
   The downside of this approach is that you will have to write code that sets the layout dynamically.

Comment: Using 2) the report does not switch from desktop to mobile portrait for me. If I set navContentPaneEnabled: true, as a test, then the navContentPanel does appear/dissapear as expected.

Comment: I've added some additonal code to the original post to show the test code I am using to resize the report.

Comment: Please provide more info. What was the layoutType used to embed the report? Why do you use Custom Layout in the sample code?

Comment: Hello, I have it set to Custom as I want to set the DisplayOption to FitToPage. I've added the code used to create the report in the first place.

Comment: Can you set 'FitToPage' in the pbix or in portal? Because in order to be able to switch to MobilePortrait you must embed the report with MobilePortrait or with MobileLandscape.

Comment: Yeah, that works thanks. If I start the Layout off as MobileLandscape, and toggle between MobileLandscape and MobilePotrait then this works.I guess this only works because I haven't defined a MobileLandscape view.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI embed Javascript library has direct support for your case.

First you will need to create a report with mobile layout using Power BI desktop. After you created the report you can embed it using JavaScript SDK. In order to decide in which layout to embed, use the layoutType property of settings in embed configuration.

There are two layout types dedicated to mobile devices:

- MobilePortrait - Optimized for portrait view (This is the mobile
  layout you created on Power BI desktop)
- MobileLandscape - Optimized
  for landscape view. This layout looks like the regular report layout.

Load a report in mobile layout Example:

```
// Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

var embedConfiguration = {
    type: 'report',
    id: '5dac7a4a-4452-46b3-99f6-a25915e0fe55',
    embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: 'h4...rf',
    settings: {
            layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait
        }
};
```

Here is the detail guide: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile